# FileUpload in wpf ( Access to the path is denied)

Tags: wpf

```
 public void Uploader(string filename, Stream Data)
        {

            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(Data);
            string path = @"C:/Friendisc/Images";            
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(fstream);
            wr.Write(reader.ReadBytes((int)Data.Length));
            wr.Close();
            fstream.Close();
            Data.Close();
        }
```

I am getting the error: Access to the path is denied.
What do I need to do?

Also How would I upload the image on another project within the same solution?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that folder? Did you try giving Read/Write access to `Everyone`?

Comment: My bad. I had a slash at the end of the path!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File path was not proper. Issue Resolved.